# Computing ActiveRecord nil attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my Rails app I have something like this in one of the models

```
def self.calc
  columns_to_sum = "sum(price_before + price_after) as price"
  where('product.created_at >= ?', 1.month.ago.beginning_of_day).select(columns_to_sum)
end
```

For some of the rows we have `price_before` and or `price_after` as `nil`. This is not ideal as I want to add both columns and call it `price`. How do I achieve this without hitting the database too many times?

Comment: If you are using Postgresql, check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ensure the `NULL` values to be calculated as 0 by using `COALESCE` which will return the first non `NULL` value:

```
columns_to_sum = "sum(COALESCE(price_before, 0) + COALESCE(price_after, 0)) as price"
```

This would however calculate the sum prices of all products.

On the other hand, you might not have to do this if all you want to do is have an easy way to calculate the price of one product. Then you could add a method to the `Product` model

```
def.price
  price_before.to_i + price_after.to_i
end
```

This has the advantage of being able to reflect changes to the price (via price_before or price_after) without having to go through the db again as `price_before` and `price_after` will be fetched by default.

But if you want to e.g. select records from the db based on the price you need to place that functionality in the DB.

For that I'd modulize your scopes and join them again later:

```
def self.with_price
  columns_to_sum = "(COALESCE(price_before, 0) + COALESCE(price_after, 0)) as price"

  select(column_names, columns_to_sum)
end
```

This will return all records with an additional `price` reader method.

And a scope independent from the one before:

```
def self.one_month_ago
  where('product.created_at >= ?', 1.month.ago.beginning_of_day)
end
```

Which could then be used like this:

```
Product.with_price.one_month_ago
```

This allows you to continue modifying the scope before hitting the DB, e.g. to get all Products where the price is higher than x

```
Product.with_price.one_month_ago.where('price > 5')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the sum of price_before and price_after for each individual record (as opposed to a single sum for the entire query result), you want to do it like this:

```
columns_to_sum = "(coalesce(price_before, 0) + coalesce(price_after, 0)) as price"
```

I suspect that's what you're after, since you have no `group` in your query. If you are after a single sum, then the answer by @ulferts is correct.